# How to install Jquery-ui in storybook?

Tags: jquery-ui, storybook

I am trying to use jquery-ui in my project based on storybook.

It always give me error of JQuery not defined.Can anyone help me in resolving this issues.

I have also tried putting the below code in ./storybook/main.js

```
config.plugins.push(
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: "jquery",
    jQuery: "jquery",
  })
);
```

but didn't work.

FYI... I already have installed jquery from npm .

Comment: Found this helpful thread: https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/327